# Qidi X-Pro - Trouble Printing - Home Settings Seem Off

Tags: firmware, software, qidi-x-pro

So I have had problems straight out of the box with this printer.

After going through a lot of leveling / slicing things I decided to check what the printer "*thinks*" is its home settings.

After the following procedure:
▶ **Factory Reset**
▶ **Power Off / On**
▶ **Manual Mode**
▶ **Home Button**

And, looking at:
▶ **System**
▶ **Info**

I get the following position information:

- X: 263.9994 mm
- Y: 153.9987 mm
- Z: 154.0000 mm

---

*Please note:*

*A relative who has another Qidi (X-Plus) when he homes it his info is exact, X: 0.0000, Y: 0.0000, Z: 200.0000*

Comment: I guess that system info is unrelated to the printer home position. Basically, the system info is the printer volume, in the sense of travel, the printing volume is smaller due to the two hotends.

Comment: Appreciate the comment, but from what I have been able to find online + a relative who has another Qidi (X-Plus) when he homes it his info is exact, X: 0.0000, Y: 0.0000, Z: 200.0000. But if you are saying that what the Info says has no play in the GCODE / Slice than alright, I can accept that.

Comment: It is strange that the printer of the relative shows the correct positioning after homing. While it is difficult to explain why it is different, I could suggest as an answer to create a G-code script file that homes the printer and moves the nozzle to the origin [0, 0, 0]. You can then check the info page. It could well be that there is a bug in the firmware displaying the position. Your reported x, y, z values would suggest that the platform is all the way down and to the back (+4 mm) and all the way to the right (+33 mm). Maybe add a photo of the position would help.

Comment: Oscar, I will try that when I am home tonight. Will snap a photo while I'm at it :)